# One class makes instances of another class. These instances need to use information in original class, how to organize?

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to object oriented programming and I still have trouble organizing my programs.

I'm making a simulation of a factory in c#. I have one instance of a `Simulation` class. When initialized, the constructor creates several instances of a `Machine` class.

The `Simulation` class has an event list. The `Machine` class has methods that need to add events to this list. Right now, the only way I see how to do this is to pass a reference of the simulation to the `Machine` constructor. However, these seems messy to me and I feel like there has got to be a better way of organizing this.

```
public class Simulation
{
    public LinkedList<Event> event_list = new LinkedList<Event>();

    public Simulation()
    {
        Machine m1 = new Machine(this);
        Machine m2 = new Machine(this);
    }

    static void Main(string args[])
    {
        Simulation sim = new Simulation();
    }
}

public class Machine
{
    public Simulation sim;

    public Machine(Simulation sim)
    {
        this.sim = sim;
    }

    public void Schedule_Event()
    {
        sim.event_list.AddLast(new Event(etc etc));
    }
}

public class Event
{
}
```

Is there a way to add events to `Simulation.event_list` without having to pass the `this` reference? In a sense each Machine "belongs" to the Simulation class, and I want to show this somehow.

Comment: why *couple* Machine with Simulation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a method in `Machine` that returns `Event` objects, then `Simulation` can take care of adding it to `event_list`:

```
public class Simulation
{
    public LinkedList<Event> event_list = new LinkedList<Event>();

    public Simulation()
    {
        Machine m1 = new Machine();
        Machine m2 = new Machine();

        event_list.AddLast(m1.GetEvent());
        event_list.AddLast(m2.GetEvent());
    }

    static void Main(string args[])
    {
        Simulation sim = new Simulation();
    }
}

public class Machine
{
    public Machine() {}

    public Event GetEvent()
    {
        return new Event(etc etc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems pretty much ok to me, I'd just hide the event_list implementation in the Simulation class:

```
public class Simulation
{
    private LinkedList<Event> event_list = new LinkedList<Event>();

    public void addEven(Event x) {event_list.Add(x); }
}
```

passing this in constructor is ok, if you really want to you can put a factory method in simulation:

```
public class Simulation
{
    public Machine CreateNewMachine() { return new Machine(this); }
}
```

to just allow `Machine m1 = Simulation.CreateNewMachine()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a more [Observer-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) type approach, using `Action<T>`

Add a public action to Machine:

```
public class Machine
{
    public Action<Event> EventAdded;

    private void Schedule_Event()
    {
        if(EventAdded != null)
            EventAdded(new Event());
    }
}
```

And Subscribe to the action upon creation:

```
public class Simulation
{
    public LinkedList<Event> event_list = new LinkedList<Event>();

    public Simulation()
    {

        Machine m1 = new Machine() { EventAdded = AddEvent };
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Simulation sim = new Simulation();
    }

    public void AddEvent(Event e)
    {
        event_list.AddLast(new Event(etc etc));
    }
}
```

Then, the only contract you have between your two objects is the `Event` type.